# propensity score weighting in estimating population mean

Tags: r, missing-data, propensity-scores, weighted-mean

I have a survey data like, it has three covariates, age, gender and marital status:

```
Age  single.male  married.male   single.female  married.female  

<30    20.0         21.0            16.0           16.0        
       24/25        5/16            11/12          2/4  

>30    30.0         36.0            18.0            NA        
       15/20        2/10            8/12           0/4
```

The fraction number is the respondent rate, the number above is respondent means of an incomplete variable. Note that the respondent rate in the right corner is **0**.
I want to get **weighted mean from response propensity stratification**, with three categories defined by response rates: less than 0.4, 0.4 to 0.8, greater than 0.8.

While I read tutorials about missing data operation, but still have no ideas about how to estimate the propensity scores for each category and the weighted mean.

Thanks in advance for anybody provides ideas/hints!